# Methodology to time series data pattern recognition

Tags: pattern-matching, signal-processing, pattern-recognition

I did some researches on SO and found many related questions/answers about pattern recognition. I was hesitating whether to post this question because this could be duplicated... But since I'm a noob in this research area and there're too much information overwhelming my head, I'm worry about that I still can't properly solve my problem after learning those concepts. So I decide to ask, probably again.

I have such a plot of data

[image]

The blue part gives an image of how normal data should change. But that is not the interesting point. After that, the data should remain constant, steady to a specific value. However, because of exogenic factors, there are jitters occasionally appearing there.

I want to know when such kind of jitters occur, and how many of them. A possible result to  the plot of data could be: t1_start, t1_end, with 5 jitters, and t2_start, t2_end, with 5 jitters.

The shown case can be a simplified version. The jitters can occur on dynamic data with different amplitudes. I also want to know if this belongs to the fields like pattern recognition, signal processing, etc, with those knowledge one is possible to come up with solutions.